# How to Root SpreadTrum SC6830 Kernel 2.6.35.7

Tags: rooting

Model - Callbar A1
Android - 2.3.5
Kernel Version – 2.6.35.7
Software version – 2.3.001.P1.12065
Hardware version – P1
CPU – SC6820 (1 GHz.)
Screen – 3.5” HVGA

I tried several methods such as Doom Lord, Super One Click, Unlock Root, Z4Root to root the phone but none worked.

Tried ADB to manually root the phone through commands but almost every command returns – “Permission Denied” or “Read Only System”. However files su, SuperUsr.apk, Busy Box were easily pushed into /data/local/tmp. Further steps like making local.prop and onwards could not be executed and returned above stated errors.

Also tried modifications by putting update.zip on SD Card root and running Android Recovery System but this method also returned error “Signature Verification Failed”.

Tried Nautilus on Linux Mint with OpenSSH while running DroidSSH on the phone but could not mount device by any means.

Scanned my device with ‘X-Ray’ app which reported that device or firmware I am using had been patched and is not vulnerable to any of the exploit available at the moment.

I desperately need rooting to remove pre-installed bloatwares and applications to free internal memory which is very less. I am trying to root phone for the last several days but every method has failed. Can any one help ?

I am providing complete details of System Memory Map, MTD Tables, Symbolic Links, Directory Permissions and File Permissions of my android phone.  I hope some one having knowledge of android system can help me by suggesting custom exploit after going through details given below.

**## system memory map**

```
00000000-00000000 : sprd-battery.0

00000061-00000061 : sprd-sdhci.0

00000064-00000064 : sprd-sdhci.1

00463000-0047ffff : System RAM

004e0000-004fefff : System RAM

01a00000-0fffffff : System RAM

0452c000-04a08fff : Kernel text

04a24000-04b65a67 : Kernel data

0eee0000-0eefffff : ram_console.0

84000000-840000ff : NK reserved I/O

8e002000-8e002fff : sprd_spi.0

8e003000-8e003fff : sprd_spi.1

9c004300-9c004400 : example.0

a0010000-a0010097 : Mali-300 GP

a0011000-a001102f : Mali-300 L2 cache

a0012000-a0012027 : Mali-300 PMU

a0013000-a0013023 : Mali-300 MMU for GP

a0014000-a0014023 : Mali-300 MMU for PP

a0018000-a00190ef : Mali-300 PP

e0002000-e0002fff : sc8800g_dcam.0

e0006000-e0006fff : sprd-sdhci.0

e0007000-e0007fff : sprd-sdhci.1

e0010000-e0017fff : sprd_nand

e0024000-e0024fff : serial_res0

e0025000-e0025fff : serial_res1

e0028000-e0028fff : sc8810-i2c.0

e0029000-e0029fff : sc8810-i2c.1

e002a000-e002afff : sc8810-i2c.2

e002b000-e002bfff : sc8810-i2c.3

e0036000-e0036fff : serial_res2

e0037280-e00372c4 : sprd-tp.0

e003c000-e013bfff : dwc_otg.0
```

**## mtd table**

```
NAND device: Manufacturer ID: 0x2c, Chip ID: 0xbc (Micron NAND 512MiB 1,8V 16-bit)

Good Block: 4034  Bad Block: 0  Reserved Block: 62

dev:        size       erasesize  name

mtd0: 00040000 00020000 "spl"

mtd1: 00080000 00020000 "2ndbl"

mtd2: 00040000 00020000 "params"

mtd3: 00080000 00020000 "vmjaluna"

mtd4: 00a00000 00020000 "modem"

mtd5: 003c0000 00020000 "fixnv"

mtd6: 003c0000 00020000 "backupfixnv"

mtd7: 00500000 00020000 "dsp"

mtd8: 003c0000 00020000 "runtimenv"

mtd9: 00a00000 00020000 "boot"

mtd10: 00a00000 00020000 "recovery"

mtd11: 10e00000 00020000 "system"

mtd12: 07800000 00020000 "userdata"

mtd13: 03c00000 00020000 "cache"

mtd14: 00040000 00020000 "misc"

mtd15: 00100000 00020000 "boot_logo"

mtd16: 00100000 00020000 "fastboot_logo"

mtd17: 003c0000 00020000 "productinfo"

mtd18: 00080000 00020000 "kpanic"
```

**## symbolic links**

```
symlink("/data/bin/bash","/system/xbin/bash");

symlink("/data/bin/oprofile/lop.dump","/system/xbin/lop.dump");

symlink("/data/bin/oprofile/lop.init","/system/xbin/lop.init");

symlink("/data/bin/oprofile/lop.reset","/system/xbin/lop.reset");

symlink("/data/bin/oprofile/lop.start.kernel","/system/xbin/lop.start.kernel");

symlink("/data/bin/oprofile/lop.start.user","/system/xbin/lop.start.user");

symlink("/data/bin/oprofile/lop.stop","/system/xbin/lop.stop");

symlink("/system/bin/alsa_aplay","/system/bin/alsa_arecord");

symlink("/system/sps/FT5206/firmware/ft5206_fw.bin","/system/etc/firmware/ft5206_fw.bin");

symlink("/system/sps/headset-soc/ko/headset.ko","/system/lib/modules/headset.ko");

symlink("/system/sps/mali/ko/mali.ko","/system/lib/modules/mali.ko");

symlink("/system/sps/mali/ko/ump.ko","/system/lib/modules/ump.ko");

symlink("/system/sps/msg2133/firmware/henghao_fw.bin","/system/etc/firmware/henghao_fw.bin");

symlink("/system/sps/msg2133/firmware/huangze_fw.bin","/system/etc/firmware/huangze_fw.bin");

symlink("/system/sps/msg2133/firmware/oufeiguang_fw.bin","/system/etc/firmware/oufeiguang_fw.bin");

symlink("/system/sps/rda5802/ko/rda5802.ko","/system/lib/modules/rda5802.ko");

symlink("/system/sps/rtl8723as/firmware/rlt8723a_chip_b_cut_bt40_fw","/system/etc/firmware/rtl8723as/rlt8723a_chip_b_cut_bt40_fw");

symlink("/system/sps/rtl8723as/firmware/rtk8723_bt_config","/system/etc/firmware/rtl8723as/rtk8723_bt_config");

symlink("/system/sps/rtl8723as/ko/8723as.ko","/system/lib/modules/8723as.ko");

symlink("/system/sps/snd_dummy_alsa_audio/ko/snd_dummy.ko","/system/lib/modules/snd_dummy.ko");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/boot_must_complete.sh","/system/xbin/boot_must_complete.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/bin/df");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/bin/mkdir");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/bin/rm");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/ash");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/busybox");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/bzip2");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/cp");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/du");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/env");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/find");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/grep");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/hexdump");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/killall");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/md5sum");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/reset");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/tar");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/uname");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/uptime");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/vi");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox","/system/xbin/which");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/gcom.arm","/system/xbin/gcom.arm");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/gsnap.save_anr_tombstones.sh","/system/xbin/gsnap.save_anr_tombstones.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/ll","/system/xbin/ll");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/localtime","/system/etc/localtime");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.bt.service.sh","/system/xbin/logs4android.bt.service.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.bt.sh","/system/xbin/logs4android.bt.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.sdcard.umount.sh","/system/xbin/logs4android.sdcard.umount.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.sh","/system/xbin/logs4android.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4modem.sh","/system/xbin/logs4modem.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/lrz","/system/xbin/lrz");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/lsof","/system/xbin/lsof");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/lsz","/system/xbin/lsz");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/mkcached.sh","/system/xbin/mkcached.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/mkinternal.sh","/system/xbin/mkinternal.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/mkswapd.sh","/system/xbin/mkswapd.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/preloadapp.sh","/system/xbin/preloadapp.sh");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/strace","/system/xbin/strace");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/tree","/system/xbin/tree");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/uevent","/system/xbin/uevent");

symlink("/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/upnvpropd.sh","/system/xbin/upnvpropd.sh");

symlink("iwmulticall","/system/bin/iwconfig");

symlink("iwmulticall","/system/bin/iwevent");

symlink("iwmulticall","/system/bin/iwgetid");

symlink("iwmulticall","/system/bin/iwlist");

symlink("iwmulticall","/system/bin/iwpriv");

symlink("iwmulticall","/system/bin/iwspy");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/cat");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/chmod");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/chown");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/cmp");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/date");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/dd");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/dmesg");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/getevent");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/getprop");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/hd");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/id");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/ifconfig");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/iftop");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/insmod");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/ioctl");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/ionice");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/kill");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/ln");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/log");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/ls");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/lsmod");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/lsof");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/mount");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/mv");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/nandread");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/netstat");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/newfs_msdos");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/notify");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/printenv");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/ps");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/reboot");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/renice");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/rmdir");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/rmmod");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/route");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/schedtop");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/sendevent");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/setconsole");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/setprop");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/sleep");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/smd");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/start");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/stop");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/sync");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/top");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/umount");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/uptime");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/vmstat");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/watchprops");

symlink("toolbox","/system/bin/wipe");
```

**## diretory permissions**

```
set_perm_recursive(0,0,0755,0644,"/system");

set_perm_recursive(0,0,0700,0644,"/system/lost+found");

set_perm_recursive(0,2000,0755,0755,"/system/bin");

set_perm_recursive(0,2000,0755,0755,"/system/xbin");
```

**## file permissions**

```
set_perm(0,0,0555,"/system/etc/ppp/ip-up-vpn");

set_perm(0,2000,0550,"/system/etc/init.goldfish.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,06750,"/system/bin/run-as");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/etc/pvplayer.cfg");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/etc/rc.local");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/opl/etc/vt_substitute.jpg");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/boot_must_complete.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/busybox");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/gcom.arm");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/gsnap.save_anr_tombstones.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/ll");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/localtime");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.bt.service.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.bt.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.sdcard.umount.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4android.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/logs4modem.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/lrz");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/lsof");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/lsz");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/mkcached.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/mkinternal.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/mkswapd.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/preloadapp.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/strace");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/tree");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/uevent");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/upnvpropd.sh");

set_perm(0,2000,0755,"/system/sps/tools-binary/tools/xmlprecopy.sh");

set_perm(0,3003,02750,"/system/bin/netcfg");

set_perm(0,3004,02755,"/system/bin/ping");

set_perm(1000,1000,0640,"/system/etc/bluetooth/auto_pairing.conf");

set_perm(1002,1002,0440,"/system/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf");

set_perm(1002,1002,0440,"/system/etc/bluetooth/input.conf");

set_perm(1002,1002,0440,"/system/etc/bluetooth/main.conf");

set_perm(1002,1002,0440,"/system/etc/dbus.conf");

set_perm(1014,2000,0550,"/system/etc/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks");

set_perm(3002,3002,0444,"/system/etc/bluetooth/blacklist.conf");
```

Comment: I took the freedom to add your question to our "rooting-master-index" ([How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)). You might want to check there, maybe one of the methods mentioned can help you. If so, don't hesitate to answer your own question here if you succeeded!

Comment: What Android version is it running?

Comment: As part of my query already, its Android 2.3.5. Device Build Date is October 2012 and has been patched for commonly available exploits.

Comment: @Izzy Thanx. May be, it can catch some one's eye there... some one, with proper solution.

Comment: That's another helpful possibility, of course :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

SuperOneClick, and other one click root methods use a rootkit exploit that has been patched in the newer versions of Android.

To root the newer versions of Android, a new exploit is needed. You would have to find a way to install the binaries, and set the permissions.

This *can* be done using the stock recovery - it just needs to be signed correctly, and as such, could be quite difficult.

Other ways include flashing a custom `boot.img` file using the bootloader. If your device doesn't come with a flashable bootloader then you are really out of options sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.  

I am new to android so don't know much.  However I can tell you that my handset can start in FastBoot Mode apart from Android Recovery System.  In Android Recovery System, there are only three options viz Wipe Cache Clean, Factory Restore and the Update from SD Card.  Kindly guide me keeping in view myself being new to android.  I can try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: I had signed update.zip as per procedure explained on one of the forum but it didn't work.  May be being leaner, I may have done some thing wrong.  However, during signing procedure no error had occurred and had completed successfully.  Any Way, end result of Stock Recovery was "Signature Verification Failed"

Comment: Please tell me, if I can use commands on ADB to custom exploit my phone???  There must be some way out...

Comment: Liam, Can u give me one method to root...??? Atleast one... but with specific guidelines.  Your above answer is general opinion and does not provide any specific solution.

Comment: @MSA You cannot sign the ZIP in a way your device will accept it -- it has to be signed with the manufacturers key in most cases, especially in your (and my) case this method thus will not work. The `fastboot` method Liam mentioned however *could* succeed (not sure, as this is also device-dependent).

Comment: @Izzy - Thanx, for providing insight.  You are correct as I had read it some where else also but didn't know that this applies to my device also.  Any way, I've edited my post to provide complete system details of my phone.  Kindly go through and suggest commands for ADB terminal to exploit my device.  Liam has suggested some methods but none is specific or detailed.  Being new to android, I can't understand any thing in brief.

Comment: Most manufacturers secure their devices this way. Few exceptions exist, though. And sorry: If I knew a working exploit for your device, I'd have answered and mentioned it already; speculations are reserved for comments :)

Comment: @MSA It can be *very* difficult, and sometimes impossible to root some devices. Most rooting exploits rely on bugs in the Android OS to work, however these have been patched as of late.

Comment: @Izzy OK Dude, I'll report back in case some one finds a solution.  Even though, my question has not been resolved, still I appreciate quick response by both of you.

Comment: As you are still on 2.3, you might want to check for Gingerbreak (might still work), zergRush, & co. [EvilZone](http://evilzone.org/android/how-to-root-your-android-phones/) has a good summary on that.

Comment: @Izzy they are simply rootkits. The OS has been patched for them.

Comment: If the updates are applied, yes. If not, they might still work. Remember, he's still on 2.3.5 -- do you know with which *exact* version what exploit stopped working? Both exploits I mentioned say to work for 2.3 (but none mentions up to which 3rd digit).

Comment: @Izzy : Liam is right.  Even though my device is running with 2.3.5 but device build date is 30th October, 2012.  Devices manufactured during 10/2012 (even prior to that) had been patched whether or not running with latest android.  I already had tested ZergRush through ADB which failed and reported that 'Blue Hellions Found!'.  I had read script of DoomLord and Super One Click, both of them also apply ZergRush exploit.  As told to you already, both these methods had also failed.  Gingerbreak is much older exploit... wont work.  X-Ray app too has reported that Gingerbreak wont do.

Comment: OK -- that's proof enough (+1 for that comment ;) If I had been sure of the opposite, I'd posted it as answer -- it was just a "guess" for a possibility. Sorry it didn't work out.

Comment: @Liam : Any insight please.  Can custom script be written or commands executed through ADB to copy binaries and apk files in desired directories???

Comment: I have pulled system folder from my phone and uploaded at the following link.  Can any one dig it to suggest possible method for rooting???

http://www.sendspace.com/file/uvmb8n